# How to use framebuffer targets in webgl?

Tags: webgl, framebuffer

How can I specifically use the read and write framebuffers in webgl ? Can't seem to find the constants for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of OpenGL ES 2, and therefore also not part of the current WebGL (which is based on OpenGL ES 2).

It is part of OpenGL ES 3, and planned for WebGL 2.
Have a look at the WebGL 2 standard:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/
and search for 'READ_FRAMEBUFFER'.